# Moving a project using CICD to a derivative process

Tags: azure-devops

Our main project is hosted and managed on VSTS online. We are managing the work using Features, User Stories and tasks. In addition, the code is managed and stored in Repos. We are working with pipelines and such for CICD. Last, we installed some extensions downloaded from the marketplace.

Currently, we are running on the build-in Agile process. We would like to create an inherit process and move the project to it. I’ve done that in the past but without the project using CICD.

The question is, can we do that safely without harming or endangering our code and CICD operations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CI/CD processes not related to the Work Item process. you can move to inherited process template without harming or endangering your code and your CI/CD pipelines.

Unless you touch the work items during the build (with custom scripts/API) and change fields etc. so you need to update the scripts (e.g. you change a field called "A" and in the new template is "B").